# Spreadsheet: Autopopulating Column S based on new entries of Column C and Column O

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

Current Formula works is input on Cell 2 after header.
'
//Check based on Column C (Time Format) to be during Office Hours / After Office Hours.
//During office hours (08:30 - 17:30), Cell on Column S to be $2
//After Office hours ( <08:30 && > 17:30) && Column O = "N.A" ), Cell on Column S to be $42
//After Office hours ( <08:30 && > 17:30) && Column O <> "N.A" ), Cell on Column S to be $63

```
=IF((C:C >= TIME(8,30,0)) * (C:C <= TIME(17,30,0)), "$2",
 IF((C:C < TIME(8,30,0)) + (C:C > TIME(17,30,0)) * (O:O = "N.A"), "$42",
     IF((C:C < TIME(8,30,0)) + (C:C > TIME(17,30,0)) * (O:O <> "N.A"), "$63")))
```

However, because new entries would be inserted based and I do not want to physically add formula into every new entry / setting the formula to a specific number of rows as I will have to come back to add the formula again.

Added Array Formula in

```
=ArrayFormula(
IF((C:C >= TIME(8,30,0)) * (C:C <= TIME(17,30,0)), "$2",
    IF((C:C < TIME(8,30,0)) + (C:C > TIME(17,30,0)) * (O:O = "N.A"), "$42",
        IF((C:C < TIME(8,30,0)) + (C:C > TIME(17,30,0)) * (O:O <> "N.A"), "$63")))
```

)'

Error shows: Result was not automatically expanded, please insert more rows (1).
If I have a result on Row S3,
Error shows: Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in S3.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) this way the community will have better chance of what is happening on your project. Please make sure that your sample document will provide how your data looks like to your sheet.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that you're starting your formula at row 2, but your range inside the formula goes from row 1 to the bottom (i.e: C:C). You should limit that range to C2:C:

```
=ArrayFormula(
IF((C2:C >= TIME(8,30,0)) * (C2:C <= TIME(17,30,0)), "$2",
    IF((C2:C < TIME(8,30,0)) + (C2:C > TIME(17,30,0)) * (O2:O = "N.A"), "$42",
        IF((C2:C < TIME(8,30,0)) + (C2:C > TIME(17,30,0)) * (O2:O <> "N.A"), "$63")))
)
```

If you don't do this, the formula will try indefinitely to expand one more row and one more row, over and over